# SharePoint list data fill

Tags: custom-list

I have a web part page with .net controls like various fields textbox, choice fields, multiple line of text. User have to fill those fields. There is save buttons. These  controls/fields are there in sharepoint list also. When user fill all fields like name, number, country etc and click on save these data need to get save in sharepoint list in respective columns.

Can you please tell me code for the same.Thanks

Comment: This is not a good question, please tell us what you have tried and any references you have searched out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use server side object model to add items to your list on button click:

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists[TextBox1.Text].Items;

SPListItem item = listItems.Add();

item["Title"] = TextBox2.Text;
item["Stock"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
item["Return Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text);
item["Employee"] = TextBox5.Text;

item.Update();
}
```